# Maintain historical data of a model without using trigger in django

Tags: django

I have created HistoryModel replica of a Model. Then I am trying to keep the historical data of that model without using database trigger or any django api. For that, in the edit section of my views.py I have written as below: Basically trying to enter the same data before saving the new value to the actual model.

```
def computer_edit(request, id=None):
 instance = get_object_or_404(Computer, id=id)
 form = ComputerForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
 if form.is_valid():
    hist = HistoryComputer(instance)  #**<< getting error here**
    hist.save()
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
    return redirect('djform-home')
 context = {
     "title": 'Edit ' + str(instance.computer_name),
     "instance": instance,
     "form": form,
 }
 return render(request, "djform/computer_entry.html", context)
```

Can we do like that way?

Comment: What about [**`django-simple-history`**? https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes correct. django-simple-history is quicker and easiest way to keep historical records.